# jquery events on json parsed through popcorn

Tags: jquery, json, popcornjs

Does anyone know why jquery events don't work with json data parsed through Popcorn.js JSON Parser?

I want to call a function when the link is clicked. And the link in question is in the json file. The file seems to be parsed as expected, and popcorn footnotes appear as expected. I can follow the parsed link but no event is fired.

Here's a piece of code I'm working on:

```
<script>
$(function() {

     var popcorn = Popcorn("#video");
     popcorn.parseJSON ("data/data.json");

     $("a[href='gohere.html']").click(function() {
           alert("clicked!"); //should display the message, but doesn't         
     });
});
</script>
```

And the JSON file looks like this:

```
{
 "data": [
    {
        "footnote": {
            "start":"1",
            "end":"3",
            "target":"footnote-container",
            "text":"<a href='gohere.html'>Go Here</a>"
        }
    },
    {
        "footnote": {
            "start":4,
            "end":7,
            "target":"footnote-container",
            "text":"Another piece of text."
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delegation with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
 $('body')on('click','a[href="gohere.html"]',function() {
       alert("clicked!"); //should display the message, but doesn't         
 });
```

replacing `'body'`(Not necessary but more efficient) with the closest ancestor that is static and exists at the time of dom ready.  This will bind the event handler to that element - which in turn listens for the event as it bubbles up from the given selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) inside a callback function from `parseJSON` or some other `ajax` derivative.

```
$("a[href='gohere.html']").on('click', function() {
       alert("clicked!");        
 });
```

Comment: No, nothing has changed. Both mine and your method work when I just put the link in the html. But it doesn't when it is created through JSON parsing.

Comment: Okay, well the issue is that the `parseJSON` runs asynchronously, so the code to attach the event handler is running before the element is created in the DOM via parsing the JSON. Can you do a callback in the `parseJSON` and put the `.on('click')...` code in there? That will work.